# How to deal with old web site with security issues?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I recently landed on old web application which is full of old school tricks

1. GET param : user info in URL parameters
2. Session informations
3. Hidden elements used for storing information
4. HTML/JS/CSS dumped in the page. Without proper encoding. etc.
5. Window.open to show popups.
6. XSS issues etc.
7. Concatenated SQL string good for blind SQL attacks.

and just many more...

to make things work. Looks like application is old over past 5-7 years (ASP.NET 1.1) and looks like the application code has failed to keep pace with better security practices.

Thankfully it looks like over period browsers and security testing tools evolved very well. Helping people/customer to report so many security issues every now and then. Keeping them happy and system secure has become pain.

Can someone please let me know in case you have faced something similar and help me get to some case study or something for how to addressed this ? test tools which are "freely" available which can be used to test web sites for security on developer environment ? What strategies should be used to deal with this situation ? How to progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying this: While there are open-source and free security scanner tools, none will be perfect.  And in my experience (with PHP at least) they tend to return enough false-positives that it's barely worth running them (but that could have gotten better since I last used them).  If you want to use one to try to help identify issues, by all means do so.  But don't trust the output either way (from a false-positive and a false-negative perspective).

As far as how to tackle it, I would suggest a step-by-step approach.  Pick one type of vulnerability, and eliminate it across the entire application.  Then go to the next vulnerability type.  So a potential game-plan might be (ordered by severity and ease of fixing):

1. Fix all SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

   Go through the code, find all places where it does SQL queries, and make sure they are using prepared statements and that nothing can get in.
2. Fix all XSS vulnerabilities

   Find all places where local information (user-submitted or otherwise) is properly sanitized and escaped (depending on the use-case).
3. Fix all CSRF vulnerabilites

   Go through the site and make sure that all the form submissions are properly using a CSRF token system to protect them from fraudulent requests.
4. Fix any and all authentication and session fixation vulnerabilities

   Make sure the authentication and session systems are secure from abuse.  This involves making sure your cookies are clean and that any session identifiers are rotated often.  And make sure you're storing passwords correctly...
5. Fix and information injection vulnerabilities

   You state that there is user information in URLs and hidden form elements.  Go through all of them and change it so that the user cannot *inject* values where they shouldn't be able to.  If this means storing the data into a session object, do so.
6. Fix all information disclosure vulnerabilities

   This is related to the former point, but slightly different.  If you use a username in the URL, but can't do anything by changing it, then it's not an injection vulnerability, it's just a disclosure issue.  Mop these up, but they are not nearly as critical (depending on what's disclosed of course).
7. Fix the output

   Fix the encoding issues and any method that might generate invalid output.  Make sure that everything is sane when it's outputted.

The important thing to note is that anything that you fix **will** make the application safer.  If it's a live application right now, don't wait!  Don't try to do everything, test and release.  Pick a reasonable sized target (2 to 4 days of work max), complete the target, test and release.  Then rinse and repeat.  By iterating through the problems in this manor, you're making the site safer and safer as you go along.  It will seem like less work to you because there is always an end in sight.

Now, if the application is severe enough, it may warrant a full rewrite.  If that's the case, I'd still suggest cleaning up at least the big ticket items in the existing application prior to starting the rewrite.  Clean up the SQL Injection, XSS and CSRF vulnerabilities at a bare minimum prior to doing anything else.

It's not an easy thing to do.  But taken a small bite at a time, you can make significant progress while staying *above water*...  Any little bit will help, so treat the journey as a series of steps rather than a whole.  You'll be better off in the end...

Answer (score 1):

Well, a google on each of the issues will help fix it, so I'll assume you're just worried about the actual risks.

1. This is easy to fix, just change to `$_POST`, which is a bit more secure, especially when used with session tokens.
2. This is still widely used, so I don't see an issue?
3. Meh, so long as that data is checked server side, and if it doesn't verify, the user has to relog or similar, this is acceptable. Of course, session is preferred, or even cookies.
4. Tidying up is just a long job, no issues unless passwords etc are being revealed in the JS. Css + html are almost always unencoded, so this seems fine.
5. I'm just not a fan of popups, and never use them, can't help here.
6. Well, host the script locally if possible, and sanitize any XSS that are essential, by stripping tags, URL encoding that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly this situation a couple of years ago on an e-commerce web site. It was in ASP.NET 1.1 and was absolutely appalling in terms of code quality and security practices. Further, I was told by management that a re-write was absolutely out of the question, and could not convince them to budge on that.

Over the course of 2 years I managed to get this system PCI-DSS compliant. This means we had to close all of those security loopholes one by one, and put in place practices to ensure they could not happen again.

The first problem is you have to find all the bugs and security flaws. You can use external vulnerability probing tools (I recommend [QualysGuard](https://www.qualys.com/)). But manual testing is the only way to get complete coverage. Write out old fashioned test scripts to test for XSS, SQL injection, CSRF etc. and enlist the help of testers to run through these scripts. If you can automate these tests, it is well worth doing. But don't avoid covering a test case just because its too hard to automate. If you can afford security consultants, have them help you scope out the test coverage and write test cases.

This will give you:
a) a list of bugs/flaws
b) a repeatable way to test if you actually fixed each one

Then you can start refactoring and fixing each flaw.

The process I followed is:
step 1: refactor, step 2: test & release, step 3: go back to step 1.
I.e. there is a continuous cycle of fixing, testing & releasing. I would recommend you to commit to regular deployments to your production systems e.g. monthly, and squeeze as many "refactorings" into each release cycle as you can.

I found Automated security tools are almost useless due to:
a) they can provide you with a false sense of security
b) they can give you so many false positives that you are sent off on meaningless tangents instead of working on real security threats.

You really need to get to grips with the nature of each security vulnerability and understand exactly how it works. A good way to do this is to research each flaw (eg. start with OWASP top 10), and write a document that you could give to any developer on your team that would explain to them exactly what each flaw is you are trying to protect against and why. I think too often we reach for tools to help fix security flaws, thinking we can avoid the effort of really understanding each threat. Generally speaking, tools are only useful to improve productivity - you still have to take charge and run the show.

Resources:

1)Read the [OWASP top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main).

2)The PCI-DSS specification is also really good stuff and helps you to think holistically about security - ie covering way more than just web applications, but databases, processes, firewall, DMZ/LAN separation etc. Even if its over the top for your requirements, its well worth browsing through.